# Django Error while trying to create 2 files of urls in different apps

Tags: django

I am trying to create a Django project for the first time, I have a problem in my project
when I try to run it I get a long error which ends with:

> line 6
> 07, in url_patterns
> raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'djangoProject.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

in the beginning the code worked and the API worked as well with "skills" app, but after I added the "projects" app, I get the error as above

I believe I'm doing something wrong, maybe the way I'm building the project is wrong.

What I'm trying to do is have 3 different API's - with the "Skill", "Experience" and "Projects"

this is the link to the product, if you look at the commits, if you go 1 commit back - it works, if you look at the current commit - it does not work

https://github.com/itzikd1/DjangoProject

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue -
inside my view i did

```
    path('', views.ExperienceSerilizer.as_view()),
```

instead of

```
    path('', views.ExperienceListCreate.as_view()),
```